# Mongo DB error Nested type initialization C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to create a new document in Mongo DB, but I have 2 problems.
My Code:

```cs
        internal class Doc
        {
            internal int ItemID { get; set; }
            internal string Some { get; set; }
            internal List<Slot> Slots { get; set; }
            internal List<Event> Events { get; set; }
        }
        internal class Slot
        {
            internal int FirstID { get; set; }
            internal int SecondID { get; set; }
            internal int Role { get; set; }
        }
        internal class Events
        {
            internal int Event { get; set; }
            internal int Time { get; set; }
        }

        internal static async void Create(int itemId, string some, int firstId, int secondId)
        {
            var doc = new Doc()
            {
                ItemID = itemId,
                Some = some,
                Slots =
                {
                    new Slot()
                    {
                        FirstID = firstId,
                        SecondID = secondId,
                        Role = 2
                    } // NullReferenceException at here
                },
                Events =
                {
                    
                }

                
            };

            await Mongo.MyCollection.InsertOneAsync(doc);
        }
```

First problem: the code stops at the line that I marked with a comment, with an error System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".
Second Problem: Even if I remove "new Slot", then I just have an empty document in MongoDB.

Comment: You need to intiliaze collection valued properties  to enable their use with object initializer syntax. `class Doc { List<Slot> Slots { get; set; } = new(); }`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you, it helped to solve the first problem. However, the document is created empty and there is only a field with an ID from Mongo.